# PreparedStatement (Java) using Oracle SDO_RELATE()

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, spatial

I want to query rows with a spatial reference from a Oracle database table.
As far as I have understood, using prepared statements (Java) is the most efficient way to do this, also preventing sql injection.
However prepared statements only allow changing the variable but not the column. In case of sdo_relate the sdo_relate function acts like a column. How can I use bind variables (using ? as placeholder) in Java to replace the coordinates in SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY()?

```
SELECT *
FROM exampletable 
WHERE SDO_RELATE(footprint, SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1.0546875, 41.50857729743939, 23.906249999999996, 54.05938788662357)), 'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE';
```

What I want to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM exampletable 
WHERE SDO_RELATE(footprint, SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,3),  SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(?, ?, ?, ?)), 'mask=anyinteract') = 'TRUE';
```

Comment: The *name* of the function has to be supplied as a fixed value. The *arguments* to the function are still variables and can be provided/set with placeholders like any other variable. What problem/error did you have with the second block of code you showed?

Comment: You may also use Java datatypes available in Oracle`s JDBC: [JGeometry](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11829/oracle/spatial/geometry/JGeometry.html#JGeometry_int__int__int____double___)